# Determinant applications for 16 year olds

Tags: secondary-education, linear-algebra

I am teaching matrices, determinants and systems to a class of 16-year-olds.

As you can expect, they do not know calculus or linear algebra.

What they do know is a little bit of matrices (how to multiply and invert them, for instance), some plane geometry, some spacial geometry, some analytical geometry, and most elementary functions: linear, quadratic, exponential, modular, trigonometric.

I had to explain what subjects they have studied because it must vary wildly from country to country.

In this context, I am having great trouble in finding real-world applications and examples of determinants being applied to do anything at all. The only examples I could show are:

Area of a triangle given the coordinates A,B,C;
Cramer's rule for solving systems of linear equations.
That being said, if anyone can think of any example I could use in my class, please tell me! Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can find a lot of applications in old college algebra and analytic geometry texts: [google books search for determinants+analytic-geometry, date restricted to be between 1840 and 1930](https://www.google.com/search?q=determinants+%22analytic+geometry%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1840%2Ccd_max%3A1930&tbm=bks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can go deeper than area of a triangle. This leads to computing the area of a polygon, and the volume of a polyhedron, two very common
and important calculations.

---

[image: TetraVol]

     
<sup>[Wolfram Demo by Ed Pegg](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TetrahedronVolume/)</sup>

---

See also [this discussion re determinants](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/9770/511) here on MESE.
Nearly every video game uses determinants somewhere deep in the code:
The signed tetrahedron volume indicates whether the apex is to the
positive or negative side of the plane containing the base.
And deciding sidedness is a key calculation for collision detection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you would count it as a 'real world' example, but you have enough to define the Alexander polynomial and so prove (modulo invariance) the non-triviality of small knots (or bigger ones with a computer).